# how to download file more than 25MB to local system in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, download

This is html file from where I was reading file and I want to save file to local system which is more than 25MB in size?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Deom for upload and Download</title>
<script>
function upload()
{
    var div = document.getElementById('main');
    var file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];

    /* I want to  download file to the local system  */
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <input type="file" id="file" onchange=upload()>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you trying to upload a file or download a file? The code you have looks like you're trying to upload a file. If so, the file is already on the user's file system, so why would you want to download it again?

Comment: yes, I want to download file which is uploaded by the above code. so please tell me  js code  to download this file at client side.

Comment: I used the <a> tag with download and href attribute but it's not working properly.